# Trying to identify something that just popped up?

Tags: identification, outdoor

Many brackets of 7 thin serrated leaves. has scent

[image: unknown plant]

Comment: This plant is a Marigold

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a young marigold. Marigold leaves are aromatic.